# How to set the number of partitions for newAPIHadoopFile?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

The "old" `SparkContext.hadoopFile` takes a `minPartitions` argument, which is a hint for the number of partitions:

```
def hadoopFile[K, V](
  path: String,
  inputFormatClass: Class[_ <: InputFormat[K, V]],
  keyClass: Class[K],
  valueClass: Class[V],
  minPartitions: Int = defaultMinPartitions
  ): RDD[(K, V)]
```

But there is no such argument on `SparkContext.newAPIHadoopFile`:

```
def newAPIHadoopFile[K, V, F <: NewInputFormat[K, V]](
  path: String,
  fClass: Class[F],
  kClass: Class[K],
  vClass: Class[V],
  conf: Configuration = hadoopConfiguration): RDD[(K, V)]
```

In fact `mapred.InputFormat.getSplits` takes a hint argument, but `mapreduce.InputFormat.getSplits` takes a `JobContext`. What is the way to influence the number of splits through the new API?

I have tried setting `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize` and `fs.s3n.block.size` on the `Configuration` object, but they had no effect. I am trying to load a 4.5 GB file from `s3n`, and it gets loaded in a single task.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-5861 is relevant, but it suggests that I should already see more than one split, since the default block size is 64 MB.

Comment: what about `"mapred.min.split.size"`, I would imagine the new api would still respect that if they didn't give a new way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `newApiHadoopFile` allows you to pass a configuration object so in that you can set `mapred.max.split.size`.

Even though this is in the `mapred` namespace since there is seemingly no new option I would imagine the new API will respect the variable.